# Bootstrap CSS not displaying correctly with Bower

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower

I am working on an Angular application and have installed Bootstrap using Bower. On my index.html file I have the bootstrap js and css files, both minified.

When I view my app in a browser the navbar is not displaying as expected. Here is the code for the navigation bar I have on my page.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="home">Akeva</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="companies">Companies</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS adds the background colour and the menu items align horizontally but the rest of the navigation does not look how it should.

Here is how the navigation is appearing:
[how the menu is display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au9ym.png)

Any ideas on why the Bootstrap nav is not appearing as expected?

Comment: `.navbar-inverse` and `.bg-inverse` should be `.navbar-dark` and `.bg-dark` to comply with Bootstrap 4.  Otherwise this functions exactly as the code you've presented suggests it would.

Comment: You should install `ui-bootstrap` also: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ Otherwise it wont really work as expected.

Comment: Agree with @ErvinSzilagyi as there are too many minute differences between the original and the Angularized version to not cause a lot of hair-pulling while debugging.